# can i use resharper 4.5 with visual studio 2010 beta

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

should this work or do i need to wait for a new resharper release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like v5 will be the one to go for.

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/resharper-50/

Answer (score 1):

It may work, but I wouldn't count on it. Instead, use the [Resharper Preview for VS 2010](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Early+Access+Program;jsessionid=D9624BE738C5AA620F402DAE91377A68) (early access program) which is in active development and will remain so until Visual Studio is finalized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for a new release, but there is a preview release specifically for VS2010:

- [ReSharper for Visual Studio 2010 (Preview)](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+for+Visual+Studio+2010+%28Preview%29)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers ...
When you think about buying ReSharper - just go ahead:

> All ReSharper 4.5 purchases made on or after October 15, 2009, qualify for a FREE upgrade to ReSharper 5.0

[found here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/index.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper build 5.0.1526.25 now supports VS2010. Get it form here: http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds

Answer (score 0):

As of today's date (and probably previously), R# 4.5 works with Visual Studio 2010 but is not optimised nor does it include some of the newer features that version 5 uses.

Additionally, you will lose some of those productivity-enhancing keyboard shortcuts if you do not remember which ones you use regularly.  Since Visual Studio 2010 has a lot of the features of version 4.5 anyway (auto type inclusion, remove and sort using statements, etc) then there is not much point in using R# 4.5 with it.

I love Resharper but version 5 has a very high memory overhead - which some development machines do not have.  4 gig is a virtual minimum for a machine running the latest VS and R# releases due to the background compiles that R# does.